# pyang DSDL plugin to create a Relax NG schema

Tags: xml, rpc, xml-rpc, relaxng

I have YANG files that I want to convert into xml-rpc. I have searched that we can do it by using pyang DSDL plugin to create a Relax NG schema and then create RPC messages. I wanted to know the procedure of doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin generates a "hybrid schema", not a Relax NG schema. If you need the latter you need to continue converting; see [here](https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang/wiki/DsdlDetails).